# c# retrieve google agenda when an updat happens

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

how can i get a signal that my external agenda in my own app needs to be updated when there is a new event been made. at this moment my code looks like this but i can't retrieve a new event from google calendar. what do i do wrong.

```
public async Task<List<EventModel>> GetAllEventsAsync()
    {
        var refresToken = RetrieveRefreshTokenAndRevoke.RefreshToken();

        if (refresToken == "ok")
        {
            var tokens = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConstantJsonFileLink.TOKEN));

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"));
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKey}");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokens["access_token"]);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            try
            {
                var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(restRequest);

                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    JObject calendarEvents = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                    var allEvents = calendarEvents["items"].ToObject<List<EventModel>>();
                    return allEvents;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Coulden't connect to google agenda.");
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push

Comment: Why aren't you using the google apis .net client library?    trying setting up a watch

Comment: no i am using my own code for the api and is it a watch that i need? @DaImTo

Comment: Also when i create a new event and let my code above run when my agenda opens the new event doesn't appear in my alleventlist @DaImTo

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to find out if there were changes to any events in your google calendar.

The first and less robust solution woudl be polling.  You could run an events.list every five minutes or so and check for changes.

The second option would be to listen for changes by setting up a [watch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch) and listing for [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) the way this works is you set up a web end point on your system that listens for calls from Google calendar.  In the event a change is made to any of your events Google will notify this endpoint on your server and you will then know that you need to make a new call to the api to get any updates.

Comment: is there a tutorial that i can follow?

Comment: Im the one that makes most of these tutorials google only supplies bare minimum of samples and hardly anything for .net.  I normally only make them using the client libraries.  So probably not.  If you have already done this one it shouldn't be hard to follow the documentation and do one for watch.  just remember that you have to either set a long expiration or you will need to readd the watch when it expires.

Comment: where can i find the UUID and the token? is that the access token ? and calendar id

Comment: uuid is just a generic id i believe just send a guid,  access token is the bearer token for authorization.    calendar id is the id of the calendar you want to watch events for.

Comment: so if i us calendarId for UUID its ok and then for Token i use acces token?

Comment: Token i would use say the user id on your system something you can use to identity this flow compared to another one maybe.

Comment: does the token is needed to be an existing on? does it matter that a token already exists. i don't realy understand the floww of watch

Comment: If you read the docs you may have better luck understanding it clearly states **(Optional) Your channel token.** You dont even need to include it so i dont think it matters to much what you set it as.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Watch WatchEventAsync()
    {
        var refresToken = RetrieveRefreshTokenAndRevoke.RefreshToken();

        if (refresToken == "ok")
        {



            var tokens = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConstantJsonFileLink.TOKEN));

            var restClient = new RestClient();
            var restRequest = new RestRequest();
            restClient.BaseUrl = new System.Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/Primary/events/watch");

            Watch watch = new Watch();

            watch.Id = CalendarId;
            watch.Token = refresToken;
            watch.Type = "webhook";
            watch.Params = new Watch.Param { Ttl = "604800" };

            var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(watch, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });

            restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKeys}");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokens["access_token"]);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", model, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            try
            {
                var restResponse = restClient.Post(restRequest);

                if (restResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    JObject watchEvents = JObject.Parse(restResponse.Content);
                    return watchEvents.ToObject<Watch>();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Coulden't Create an event in google agenda.");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

// I have this for the moment